# Hlow can I change the color of text in the UIStatusBar in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to change the text color of text which is appear on UIStatusbar?i am presenting a view Controller on my RootviewController than the Status Bar color change according to my view controller  so i just want to change the text color on UIStatusBar.
if we unable to change the text color than how to fix the UIStatusBar overlapping the header in IOs7 ? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following lines in the applicationdidfinishlaunching method of app delegate file

```
self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle=UIStatusBarStyleDefault;



_mainViewController_iPhone.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 1140);

self.nav=[[UINavigationControlle alloc]initWithRootViewController:_mainViewController_iPhone];
self.window.rootViewController = self.nav;
self.nav.navigationBarHidden=YES;
appDel.navmain=nav;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {

    UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    appDel.viewbar=addStatusBar;
    addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //change this to match your navigation bar
    [self.window addSubview:addStatusBar];
}


//[_window addSubview:_mainViewController_iPhone.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks its working for me but its very tricky..